# Azure Linux App Service Not Displaying Application Logs

Tags: linux, azure, api, logging, azure-web-app-service

I've set up a linux based azure app service and am unable to see log messages from the application itself in both the "log stream" and "logs" tab of the monitoring options. It is important to note I can see start up messages in the logs for the deployed application and can see outputs when get and post requests are made to the corresponding connection url so i know its running (Also the tasks the application is written to perform are carried out). Additionally, in the "App Service Logs" tab I have "Application Logging" set to "File System" as is standard for what I'm trying to output but this hasn't resulted in any in-application logs being visible.

Lastly about a year ago I managed to set up two other linux based azure app services that work completely as desired and output the in app log messages to the stream and cannot replicate this behaviour with this one. I feel there is just some setting or property somewhere i have overlooked but no matter how many different setting tabs I investigate I cannot spot any significant differences.

Are there any somewhat hidden options or requirements to be aware of in order to get in-application logs to be outputted to a linux based app services "log stream"? Or some other solution at a higher level in the azure resource group, workspace, application insights etc that may solve this issue? Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my environment.

Go to Your App Service --> Select Diagnose and Solve Problems --> Click on Availability and Performance --> Select Application Logs

You should be able to see the Application Logs, Platform Logs and Deployment Logs here.

[image]

Log Stream gives you the live logs of your application. The logs displayed in the Application logs should be seen in the Log Stream.

[image]